# mapStateToProps for functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Is there any function similar to `mapStateToProps` so that we can connect Redux state to the functional component in React?

Is passing the state as props from parent component the only solution?

Comment: Hi you could also use the _recompose_ lib https://github.com/acdlite/recompose

Comment: Props are props; you're mapping *Redux* state to component props. The nature of the component isn't relevant.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can definitely use `mapStateToProps` with a functional component, the same way you would with a class component.

```
function MyComponent({ propOne }) {
  return <p>{propOne}</p>
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { propOne: state.propOne };
} 

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Comment: What is the difference between passing data exclusively via props and mapStateToProps?.

Comment: There is no functional difference. `mapStateToProps` gives you access to the redux store to build your props from, tho.

Comment: @Pratap The essential difference between props and mapStateToProps is the source of data. In mapStateToProps, the data source is the redux store. While in props, the data source is the parent component. Use mapStateToProps when the component can know about redux store and props when it is an independent UI/reusable component.

Answer (score 23):

### With Hooks you can use something like this

```
import React from 'react';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";

const AccountDetails = () => {

    const accountDetails = useSelector(state => state.accountDetails);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Your user name is: {accountDetails.username}</h2>
            <button onclick={() => dispatch(logout())}>Logout</button>
        </div>
    );
};


export default AccountDetails;
```

Comment: So where is the logout function?

Comment: @JasonRice I didn't include it because that's going to be specific to your implementation. For example, my logout button will fire a POST to /api/logout and clear any state in redux

Comment: it's still nice to see a simple example. Something that can be directly copy/pasted to try out.

Answer (score 13):

react-redux now has a useSelector method. That's a much cleaner approach for functional components that employ hooks. See: https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#useselector

Comment: This is fantastic .. useDispatch and useSelector

Comment: True but useSelector is not clean sometimes. In my case, change in any store value is remounting my component instead of just rerendering. Remounting is causing all the useEffects in my component to run fresh. I am still finding a solution to this. :(

Answer (score 3):

You should `connect` the component to the store at first.

The connection happen using the `connect` HOC provided by the `react-redux` package. The first paramter it takes, is a method that, given the global store, returns an object with only the properties you need in this component.

For instance:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const HelloComponent = ({ name }) =>
    <p>{ name }</p>

export default connect(
    globalState => ({ name: globalState.nestedObject.innerProperty })
)(HelloComponent)
```

To improve readability, it is common use the method `mapStateToProps`, like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    name: state.nestedObject.innerProperty
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HelloComponent)
```

Comment: While I don't see how this improves upon the already-upvoted answer, the refactoring into `mapStateToProps` contains an error that should be fixed. Although I don't see any reason to essentially duplicate the existing answer.

Comment: Due to the type of the answer, I assumed (maybe wrongly) that @sumit missed some of the basics between react and redux. Due to this assumption, I tried to give a couple more lines of explanations.

Answer (score 0):

```
     const CategoryList = (props) => {
    
      return (
           <div>
               <h3>Category</h3>
               <h5>Seçili Kategori:{props.currentCategory.categoryName}</h5>
           </div>
      );
   }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
    
        return {
            currentCategory: state.changeCategoryReducer
        }
    }
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CategoryList);
```