# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props') in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-props

i am new to react and redux and i am facinf the below error
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')
for fererence please find the attached image.
[image]

My code is

```
 import React from "react";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import "./style.css";
    
    const shop = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1 className="title">Welcome to Vshop</h1>
          <div className="item">
            <p>Apple Macbook Air</p>
            <p>Available: {this.props.numOfLaptops}</p>
            <button>Buy Now</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
        numOfLaptops: state.numOfLaptops,
      };
    };
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(shop);
```

Comment: Why did you use `this` in a function component?

Comment: i am a beginner i am following some one guide

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857738/mapstatetoprops-for-functional-component

Comment: use this **const shop(props)** then you can use props.numOfLaptops